# lftp hangs on "connecting"

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, cloud9-ide, lftp

I use lftp to transfer files from my Cloud 9 IDE to a remote host.  Recently, it seems to have stopped working.  I've raised this with the host, and they think it's working OK.  Indeed, I can connect to the ftp host via FileZilla, and via a simple browser.  I've raised it with Cloud 9, but no luck either.

I'm transferring a file using the following from the command line:

```
lftp -e "debug; set ssl:verify-certificate no; put ./res/test.txt -o test.txt; bye" -u abcd,xyz ftp.example.com
```

(the `set ssl:verify-certificate no` was an addition from a while ago, to overcome a similar connection problem that suddenly appeared... I've tried without it too... same result)

What I'm finding in C9 is that is forever trying connect, with:

```
---- Connecting to ftp.example.com (xx.xxx.xx.xxx) port 21
**** Socket error (Connection timed out) - reconnecting
---- Closing control socket
---- Connecting to ftp.example.com (xx.xxx.xx.xxx) port 21
**** Socket error (Connection timed out) - reconnecting
---- Closing control socket
---- Connecting to ftp.example.com (xx.xxx.xx.xxx) port 21
```

Difficult to offer any assistance, probably, but does anyone have any ideas at least to help me diagnose?  Any additional options to try?

Thanks.

Comment: This message means a connectivity problem, routing or firewall not passing the packets.

Comment: So you think this is likely to be an issue at the Cloud 9 end rather than the ftp host end?  Some sort of firewall set up around the IDE?

Comment: It can be on the client host and in between. Unlikely on the server side if other clients can connect.

Answer (score 6):

In my case lftp doesn't instruct ssh to use "password authentication" explicitly and it stuck waiting for a password from a keyboard

```
<--- debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
<--- debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive 
<--- Password authentication
```

after setting sftp:connect-program to `"ssh -oPreferredAuthentications=password -a -x"` I got rid of the issue.

```
lftp << !
  set sftp:connect-program "ssh -oPreferredAuthentications=password -a -x"
  open -u $USER --env-password $PROTOCOL://$HOST
  mirror -vvv -c --only-missing -P 600 $SRC_FOLDER /dbfs/mnt/$HOST/$DST_FOLDER
!
```

if you still have the issue then you can enable debug and see what is going wrong by passing `-v` to `ssh` and `-d` to `open`

```
lftp << !
  set sftp:connect-program "ssh -a -x -v"
  open -d -u $USER --env-password $PROTOCOL://$HOST
  ls
!
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after upgrading Ubuntu to 16.04 to make use of TLS 1.2. The first command issued, whether a cd or an ls would result in [Connecting...] which would hang.

It turned out that their Comcast Router had a port forwarding rule for incoming tcp port 21 (21 is ftp) to a holter monitor server. I disabled that rule and the problem went away instantly.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be caused by mismatches or permissions issues in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and `~./ssh/authorized_keys`.

After correcting the conflict with the port forwarding rule in the router, this happened again for one of the users. I fixed it by copying my (working) `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `~/.ssh/known_hosts` over hers and setting the permissions.